Can an AND gate glitch even though only one input changes "at a time"?
Can an AND gate glitch even though only one input changes "at a time"?
Suppose the inputs change with relatively low frequency (a MHz at most). Further suppose only one input changes at a time. That is, there will be at least 1 microsecond between any pair of transitions, whether for the same signal or in relation to the other signal's transition.
For example, when a controller, through it's logic, will never change both outputs in the same "clock" cycle.
Can the AND gate still glitch, or is it generally guaranteed not to under these conditions?

The rise/fall times of the input signal should not be slower than the propagation delay of the gate, otherwise it may oscillate at the input logic switching voltage.

@CarlRutschow Interesting observation, but the inputs to the AND gate are digital all right (they are not analog or anything) so I expect they will have decent rise/fall times. I suppose a Schmitt trigger near the gate would probably increase the robustness with regard to this concern.

You mention that the inputs will never change simultaneously. So, that removes one reason for the glitches on the AND gate output.
However, if there are any glitches on the inputs themselves, that will propagate to the AND gate output. If these inputs are directly coming from a flipflop output, there will not be any glitches on them but, if they come out of some combinational logic, that can have glitches.

Makes sense. I will be sure to register those outputs in the controller so they are directly coming from a flip-flop output as you mentioned.

This is the transistor arrangement of a NAND gate:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
M1 is maintained in a permanent ON state by input IN2 being held low, while IN1 is permitted to rise and fall. Since impedance between OUT and +5V is so low through M1, the other three transistors are unable to significantly alter the potential at OUT, and no undesired transitions will appear there:

The only glitches at OUT are the small peaks due to extremely fast input transitions being partially coupled capacitively to OUT, but they are too small to cause any subsequent logic gates to consider them as transitions.
A subsequent logic gate might be an inverter, to make this into an AND gate, but it doesn't change the fact that M1 above is firmly holding OUT high, even as IN1 waggles up and down.
These same arguments can be applied to NOR and OR gates. In a NOR gate, it's the lower N-channel transistors that are paralleled, one of which will be permanently switched ON, making it impossible for any other transistor to alter the output's low state.

simulate this circuit
There is one caveat to these arguments, regarding supply decoupling. When a gate's output changes state, there's a momentary spike in current consumption by that gate. It's short but significant, and if you don't have adequate power supply decoupling capacitance near that gate's supply pins, then there will be a sudden dip in supply voltage, which may cause the gates/latches in the same package (and even in other packages nearby) to behave strangely.
Ironically, then, it's not glitches at the output of the gate in question that you should worry about, but rather glitches occurring due to fast transitions in other gates altogether.

Was going to include power supply decoupling for each package as per the usual, but this answer is great at explaining why that's necessary.
